# passing selected value and a variable to a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown list dynamically created by javascript. I want to pass the selected value from that list along with another javascript variable to a different HTML page, which will call a separate javascript file using those parameters.

```
 var dates = info[3];   
 html_list += '<div class="rows" align="center" id="date_list"><h3> Please select a date for individual test analysis</h3> <br> <br><select id="date_selection">';      
                    for(var i=0; i< dates.length; i++)  {
                     html_list += '<option value="'+ dates[i] +'">"' + dates[i] + '"</option>';
                    }
                    html_list += '</select></div></div>';
document.getElementById('patient_display').innerHTML += html_list;
```

I created a form for it and tried using the onsubmit event handler but couldn't get it working. I would like something like this:

```
onsubmit( temp, this.value)
```

where temp would be a predefined variable and this.value is the selected value to be passed to a separate HTML page or even to a javascript function in that HTML page. How can this be done??

Any help much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query Strings. Let's say for example the other page is otherpage.html, then you'd link to it like this: otherpage.html?data=123.

That would be the form's action, you should construct it dynamically.

```
//let's say you have a DOM variable for the form called myForm
var value = $("select option:selected").val();
myForm.action = "otherpage.html?data=" + value;
myForm.submit(); //done.
```

Comment: would that just pass the selected value along with the variable ??

Comment: you can use query strings, like the above, to send key/value pairs. The above does not show you the exact case for some hypothetical select control, but for anything.

You need to write the code to get selected value. You can do it easily with jQuery and pseudo selectors.